# Hamiltonian System Outside Physics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, econo-physics

What are good examples of Hamiltonian systems outside physics? I heard there are financial systems that can be described by a Lagrangian, and was interested to see some examples

Comment: Read up on the Black-Scholes option pricing model. For a wryly, side-splittingly funny tale of what happens when we refuse to look to experiment and how the empirical world crushes us if we do so, then read the story of the company founded on the Black-Scholes model: [Long Term Capital Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-Term_Capital_Management)

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a list question.

Comment: This is explicitly *not* about physics, and so is off-topic.